# How to implement a "before" callback in axios

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios

I'm writing a project in `Vue.js` (using `axios`) with file upload functionality.

I need to implement an action before the `POST` request is sent in `axios`:

```
axios.post('/upload', form, {
  before: (xhr) => {
    fileObject.xhr = xhr;
  },
  onUploadProgress: (e) => {
    //emit progress event etc...
    console.log('upload progress: ' + e.loaded);
  }
}).then((response) => {
  console.log('finished...');
  //emit finished event etc...
}, () => {
  console.log('error...');
  //emit failed event etc...
});
```

Everything works except the `before` callback of course because it isn't an `axios` option. From the documentation, I know I should use an interceptor to implement hooks before requests are sent. But I can't get around it.

**Edit:**
I'd like to have something similar to Vue's `$http`:

```
this.$http.post('/upload', form, {
  before: (xhr) => {
    fileObject.xhr = xhr;
    //maybe do something else here
  },
  progress: (e) => {
    eventHub.$emit('progress', fileObject, e);
  }
}).then((response) => {
  eventHub.$emit('finished', fileObject);
}, () => {
  eventHub.$emit('failed', fileObject);
})
```

Comment: Why don't you make `xhr` request first, then when it's done - send `axios` post request (in `xhr` callback or `then` block)?

Comment: What if I wanted to do anything else (not necessarily exactly xhr stuff) before the post action? I'd love to have it all in one place. I'd like to have something similar to what you can do with Vue's $http: this.$http.post('/upload', form, {
          before: (xhr) => {
            fileObject.xhr = xhr
          },
          progress: (e) => {
            eventHub.$emit('progress', fileObject, e)
          }
        }).then((response) => {
          eventHub.$emit('finished', fileObject)
        }, () => {
          eventHub.$emit('failed', fileObject)
        })

Comment: Well, you can still keep it all in one place, but execute async requests in order instead of mixing them one inside another. It's just my opinion, keep looking if you need your approach for some reason.

Comment: Do u try to use transformRequest param in axios?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you need to call a function before each axios request, you should use an [interceptor](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#interceptors).

In your case:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  fileObject.xhr = config;
  return config;
});

axios.post('/upload', form, { ... });
```

Comment: I applied it. but it is multiple running this function